# Abelianization of $PGL(n,F)$

Tags: group-theory, general-linear-group

For any field $F$, it's known that the abelianization of $GL(n,F)$ is $F^{*}$ except for $GL(2,\mathbb{F}_{2})$. What is the abelianization of $PGL(n,F)$? It seems to me there are non-trivial elements in some cases but I cannot find good reference on it.

Comment: Since $PGL(n,F)$ is the central quotient of $GL(n,F)$, wouldn't it just be the quotient of the abelianization of $GL(n,F)$ by the image of the center?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you for the comment. It turns out that I used the same argument but got confused by wrongly concluding that the quotient is always trivial. Actually the quotient group is $F^{*}/F^{*n}$ and is trivial only in special cases.

Comment: @hyyyyy indeed ($n\ge 1$) the abelianization of $GL_n$ is the (surjective) determinant homomorphism $GL_n\to F^*$, and the image of the center (scalar matrices) by the determinant is indeed ${F^*}^n$.